# Animate a pgfplots 3d-plot

Tags: pgfplots

This question is related to [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183194/animating-a-plot-with-pgfplots). but not the same I guess as here I want to animate the view.

This issue came up in my previous question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/266121/help-with-pgf-plot/266122#266122), I want to show the maximum and minimum of the function $\sin(x)\sin(y)$ to my students. I have plotted the surface in the beamer using pgfplots. Now I am wondering if there is a way to make a small animation of the viewing angle to show the peaks and drops on the surface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, here's one option using a `\foreach` loop and `\only`; the angle can be changed using the `view` option (or one of the similar options) for the `axis` environment:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \Angle [count=\ti] in {30,60,120,150,210,240,300,330}
    {
    \only<\ti>{\begin{axis}[
    view={\Angle}{30}]
    \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360, samples=40] 
    {sin(x)*sin(y)};
    \end{axis}}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Using ImageMagick and something like

```
convert -verbose -delay 120 -loop 0 -density 300 a.pdf a.gif
```

you can get an animation:

[image]

You can also use the [`animate`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/animate) package to produce directly the animation, but this only works with Adobe Reader, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Sorry, is there supposed to be an example below the final line?  If so, it’s missing.

Comment: @Lorehead No. That final line was a leftover that I've now removed.

Answer (score 5):

Here is the version using the [animate package](https://ctan.org/pkg/animate):

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{animateinline}[poster=last, controls, palindrome]{12}%
    \multiframe{29}{iAngle=80+10}{%
        %iAngle = 80, 90, ..., 360 degrees
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[view={\iAngle}{30}]
            \addplot3[surf,domain=0:360, samples=40] 
            {sin(x)*sin(y)};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }%
\end{animateinline}%
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```